# how can i write jmeter map test case scenario with input and output result input is csv file out put should also csv file

Tags: jmeter

I need to map my test case with the input data that is present in a csv file and compare it with rest response and generate a responce csv file with that perticular test scenerio in Jmeter.
So I am providing the deviceID as input and validating the json response and writing it into a csv file. for for single occurrence I can get the value as well as I can tag my test case in the response csv file. but when I try with multiple input with multiple test case my response came up returning the last value. like: 
Validate  County ETR available with No Ticket April16PM  Hurricane Event

### lets say my input is:

Test Case                                     Device ID          Execution
Validate if Active Event                      40122480           Yes
Validate if Valid Device ID                   277136436      Yes
Validate  City ETR available with No Ticket       268698851 
Validate  County ETR available with No Ticket     18515907

bean shell code is:

```
scenario = vars.get("ScenarioName");
eventname = vars.get("C_EventName");
eventtype = vars.get("C_EventType");
areaName = vars.get("C_AreaName");
areaType = vars.get("C_AreaType");

f = new FileOutputStream("C:\\RestService\\Result.csv", true); //specify true if you want to overwrite file. Keep blank otherwise.
p = new Print`enter code here`Stream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print( scenario + ", " + eventname  + ", " + eventtype + ", " + areaName + ", " + areaType);
f.close();
```

I have increse the number of threads to 4 but the loop count is 1.

can you please help me out. in this JMeter issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Bean Shell Sampler in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675711/how-to-use-bean-shell-sampler-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend going for Beanshell-based approach as if more than one thread (virtual user) will be writing into the same file the result will be unpredictable and most probably wrong as you are creating the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) there.

The best option would be adding your variables to .jtl results file directly. To do this:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

   ```
   sample_variables=ScenarioName,C_EventName,C_EventType,C_AreaName,C_AreaType
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
3. Next time you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   the resulting .jtl file will have 5 extra columns holding the values of the aforementioned variables for each request.

References:

- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)